# Symfony 3 permissions var/cache

Tags: caching, logging, permissions, var, symfony

I am setting up Symfony 3 for a web project. I have installed it as per the SymfonyBook. When I test by accessing config.php in the web folder from the browser I get the following messages:

```
Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing:
- Change the permissions of either "app/cache/" or "var/cache/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
- Change the permissions of either "app/logs/" or "var/logs/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
```

I have already set up the permissions as described in the Symfony Book using setfacl and checked them www-data is the group owner of var folder and the cache, logs and sessions sub folders and the folder and file permissions are set to 775.

Please note this is Symfony 3 file structure not Symfony 2.

has anyone had a similar experience and managed to find a solution?

Comment: `chmod -R 775 var` is not working?

Comment: Try `sudo chmod -R 777 var/*`

Comment: Solved the problem. I had set the permissions in the project directory but I have set it up using PHPStorm to copy the files to a local server and I had not changed the permissions on the server. Apologies first time I has used this feature in PHPStorm as i usually work in the served directory

Answer (score 1):

olved the problem. I had set the permissions in the project directory but I have set it up using PHPStorm to copy the files to a local server and I had not changed the permissions on the server. Apologies first time I has used this feature in PHPStorm as i usually work in the served directory.